# Use the Google Custom Search API to search the web from Python

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine, web-crawler

I'm a newbee in Python, HTML and CSS and am trying to reverse engineer "https://github.com/scraperwiki/google-search-python" to learn the three and use the Google Custom Search API to search the web from Python. Specifically, I want to search the search engine I made through Google Custom Search "https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=000839040200690289140:u2lurwk5tko"I looked through the code made some minor adjustments and came up with the following.  "Search.py"

```
import os
from google_search import GoogleCustomSearch
#This is for the traceback
import traceback
import sys

#set variables
os.environ["SEARCH_ENGINE_ID"] = "000839...   "
os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY"] = "AIza...   "

SEARCH_ENGINE_ID = os.environ['SEARCH_ENGINE_ID']                           
API_KEY = os.environ['GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY']

api = GoogleCustomSearch(SEARCH_ENGINE_ID, API_KEY)

print("we got here\n")

#for result in api.search('prayer', 'https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=000839040200690289140:u2lurwk5tko'):
for result in api.search('pdf', 'http://scraperwiki.com'):
    print(result['title']) 
    print(result['link']) 
    print(result['snippet']) 

print traceback.format_exc()
```

And the import ("At least the relevant parts") I believe comes from the following code in google_search.py

```
class GoogleCustomSearch(object):
    def __init__(self, search_engine_id, api_key):
        self.search_engine_id = search_engine_id
        self.api_key = api_key

    def search(self, keyword, site=None, max_results=100):
        assert isinstance(keyword, basestring)

        for start_index in range(1, max_results, 10):  # 10 is max page size
            url = self._make_url(start_index, keyword, site)
            logging.info(url)

            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code == 403:
                LOG.info(response.content)
            response.raise_for_status()
            for search_result in _decode_response(response.content):
                yield search_result
                if 'nextPage' not in search_result['meta']['queries']:
                    print("No more pages...")
                    return
```

However, when I try to compile it, I get the following.

[image]

So, here's my problem. I cant quite figure out why the following lines of code don't print to the terminal. What am I overlooking?

```
print(result['title']) 
print(result['link']) 
print(result['snippet'])
```

The only thing I can think of is that I didn't take a correct ID or something. I created a Google custom search and a project on Google developers console as the quick start suggested. Here is where I got my SEARCH_ENGINE_ID and GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY from.

[image]
[image]

After I added the stacktrace suggested in the comments I got this

[image]

Am I just misunderstanding the code, or is there something else I'm missing? I really appreciate any clues that will help me solve this problem, I'm kind of stumped right now.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Line 52 of [the source](https://github.com/scraperwiki/google-search-python/blob/master/google_search.py) says `def search(self, keyword, site=None, max_results=100):`, which isn't what yours says (see your stack trace).

Comment: I figured out how to do a stack trace and posted the results above. I also tried changing line 52  from `search(self, keyword, site=None, max_results=100)` to `search(self, keyword, site, max_results=100)` which didn't work for me. However, something does seem weird about that line.

Comment: Well, you got rid of the `Null` but it's hard to see what's failing and you don't say what you are expecting.  I see `None` which could mean anything. Maybe it's working but you are getting no results back?

Comment: I'm expecting the code to print the html title, link and snippet of the google search engine I created `https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=000839040200690289140:u2lurwk5tko` based on the word given as a parameter in the api.search() function. In this case "Prayer". Am I expecting the wrong thing?